# Variance of sum of independent random variables - case of undefined density

Tags: probability

When the density $f_{X, Y}$ is not defined for independent random variables $X, Y$, is it possible to say anything beyond
\begin{align}
Var(X + Y) &= Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 \int_{\Omega} (X - E(X))(Y-E(Y)) dP,
\end{align}
in terms of simplifying the last integral?

Comment: Do $X$ and $Y$ have density functions? Just to clarify what you meant.

Comment: Would that be helpful in order to simplify the last term? I don't have a specific example in mind, but let's say the densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ do exist, while $f_{X, Y}$ is still undefined.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't make sense. To clarify: none of the densities $f_{X}$, $f_{Y}$ and $f_{X, Y}$ exist.

Comment: Existence of densities is not relevant for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are independent random variables defined on the same probability space then  the rule: $$\mathsf{Var}(X+Y)=\mathsf{Var}X+\mathsf{Var}Y$$ is valid if $\mathbb EX^2$ and $\mathbb EY^2$ are both finite.

For that we do not need a density.

Observe that because of independence:$$\begin{aligned}\int\left(X-\mu_{X}\right)\left(Y-\mu_{Y}\right)dP & =\int\left(X-\mu_{X}\right)dP\times\int\left(Y-\mu_{Y}\right)dP\\
 & =\left(\mu_{X}-\mu_{X}\right)\left(\mu_{Y}-\mu_{Y}\right)\\
 & =0
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Ok, great. I wasn't aware that integral over $\Omega$ could be factorized like this. I thought it was only possible to factorize after having obtained the integral over $\Re^n$. The reason behind your "because of independence"-argument is that the generated $\sigma$-algebras, $\sigma(X - \mu_X)$ and $\sigma(Y - \mu_Y)$, are independent, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are independent $\sigma$-algebras.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are independent they are also uncorrelated thus

$$\mathbb{V}[X+Y]=\mathbb{V}[X]+\mathbb{V}[Y]$$

Comment: Moreover, if they are independent then $f_{X,Y}=f_X\cdot f_Y$ so it should be well-defined.

Comment: My question is: what if the density $f_{X, Y}$ doesn't exist?